# how can I pick a random image(jpg) from a folder into javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 52 card images in the folder and their names are in the format of hear_n,spad_n,club_n,diam_n, where n is value from 1 to 13. These images are in jpg format. How can I pick one random image from this folder and display on my page using javascript? no short cuts please. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey friend, you should store the path of the images in an array and generate a random array in a range of the numbers of your images, then you can display random images.

Comment: another tip, here is not somewhere that people are going to read you some code, here is a place that people are helping each other and no one has time for writing a complete solution for you problem.

Comment: some tips for solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

You could try with something like this:

```
const img = document.getElementById('card-img');
const types = ['diam', 'spad', 'hear', 'club'];

const getRandomCard = () => {
  const randomType = types[Math.floor(Math.random() * types.length)];
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 13) + 1;

  img.src = `./cards/${randomType}_${randomNumber}.png`;
}
```